# Printing format Java

Tags: java

```
 out.append("Line " + (j+1) + ": ");  
 System.out.print("Line " + (j+1) + ":");
 for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length;i++){
     lotto[i] = r.nextInt(45)+1;                                                                
     out.append(lotto[i] + " ");
     System.out.print(lotto[i] + " ");
 }
```

Now it is printing as below

> Line 1: 41 7 38 20 38 39 Line 2: 12 35 5 27 4 33 Line 3: 9 3 10 15 35 2

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: what output you are expecting ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are printing the new line after printing `Line n`

You should use `println` after the inner `for` that prints the numbers.

Like

```
// print "Line n"
System.out.print("Line " + (j+1) + ":");

for (int i = 0; i < lotto.length;i++){
    lotto[i] = r.nextInt(45)+1;                                                             
    out.append(lotto[i] + " ");
    // Print in the same line the numbers
    System.out.print(lotto[i] + " ");
}
// Print the new line
System.out.println();
```